# Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery 2.0 compatibility

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-2.0

**Is twitter bootstrap 2.3.X or 3.0.0-wip compatible with jQuery 2.x?**

If not is there any intention to upgrade compatibility the future?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes they are. The only problem that may arise if use them together is if you use jQuery UI along with Bootstrap. For that you have to use [jQuery-UI-Boostrap](http://jquery-ui-bootstrap.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/)

Comment: here in the future this project no longer exist :(

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap 4** will have official support for jQuery 2 (as of [Alpha 2](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/12/08/bootstrap-4-alpha-2/)).

jQuery 1.9.1 remains the [minimum supported version](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/grunt/configBridge.json#L41).